# FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: amazon-s3, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, emr

I am trying to run a mapreduce job on EMR cluster. The version of Hadoop on EMR is 2.7.3. 
The code is used to read HFiles residing on S3 bucket. But every time I run it fails with the below error.

```
2018-02-22 20:02:11,641 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLog.createLogSyncer()Ljava/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService;
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.<init>(MRAppMaster.java:250)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.<init>(MRAppMaster.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1472)
2018-02-22 20:02:12,188 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
End of LogType:syslog
```

The actual code was designed to read files from HDFS which was all doing fine in CDH based clusters where the hadoop version is 2.6.0. However there was a requirement to read the HFiles from S3 bucket on EMR based cluster in AWS. I made few changes in the code which will allow it to read any file system. Below is the snippet of the change

```
...
Path JSONOutputjob2 = new Path( args[1] );
FileSystem.get(JSONOutputjob2.toUri(), conf2).delete(JSONOutputjob2, true);
...
```

I am passing the path as an argument and here are the options that I have tried with the file path.

```
s3n://emr-ip/path/to/the/file
s3a://emr-ip/path/to/the/file
s3://emr-ip/path/to/the/file
```

This error is really driving me crazy. I have updated my pom.xml file to use the available Hadoop version of the cluster and built the project. The build was also successful. But does not work. Any suggestions or help is much appreciated.

Edit:
I have update my pom to have the aws hadoop version i.e 2.7.3 which did not fix the issue.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading hadoop version to 2.7.3 in your build file pom.xml or build.sbt etc.? It seems to be a version mismatch issue.

Comment: I tried that already...